Error in deploying react application to github pages: cannot find git
I'm building a react app and then I'm trying to deploy it to github pages using the gh-pages node module.
Here's my package.json file:
{
  "name": "personal-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://virajkumar.github.io/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router": "^6.26.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1"
  }
}

Here's the error that I'm getting when I run "npm run deploy"(react-script for gh-pages -d build):
> personal-website@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build
 
node:events:368
    throw er // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'clean', '-f', '-d' ]

I've updated the PATH variable with where the git executable is located but the error still persists. Please help.

the git module??? you mean the git executable? You're not using the node git module are you?

I meant the git executable.

How did you install it? Why do you have the node git module as a dependency?

I installed the git executable using brew install git. I installed the git module using npm install git. I installed the git module because I thought it would work. But it didn't.

brew install git OK, so you're on a mac - and git is not recognised as an executable in a command prompt?

I can use git in the command prompt and in bash

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Don't post code or errors as image but rather copy/paste the text in your post.
